# Maven update in macOS

Tags: macos, maven, homebrew

My current maven version is 3.5.0 I would like to update this version to 3.5.4  in my Mac book macOS based system without using homebrew.

When I extracted the new version maven then the command `mvn -version` still points to the older one. It doesn't override the new version with old as if would have expected.

Comment: What do you mean with install? Usually you just extract maven and then you add it to your path in /etc/profile:
sudo vi /etc/profile
and then add something like
export MVN_HOME=/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Downloads/…/apache-maven-3.5.4

export PATH=$PATH:$MVN_HOME/bin

Also check your IDE settings, maybe you need to set it separately in there.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `new version man-version still points to the older one`? I just download the tar.gz archive and do a `sudo tar -xzf apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.tar.gz` in `/usr/local/` and afterwards `sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4 maven` and add `/usr/local/maven/bin` to my path...

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue.

1. Extract the maven
2. change the path in my `.bash_profile` file from maven-3.5.0 to maven-3.5.4
3. `export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.5.4`

   `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin`
4. Quit and reopen the command window fetching maven version.

Thus maven was updated with the latest version.